# JSON_PARSER_ERROR

Tags: apex, rest, post

Getting an error while posting a request to this class

POST Request is

```
    {
    "RequestWrapper": {

        "sap_org_Id": "US29",
        "bolNumber": "888888",

        "ProductLine": [{
            "productId": "a2SS0000000HijIMAS",
            "uom": "BAG",
            "ProductDetailLine": [{
                "orderQty": 1,
                "lotNumber": "345",
                "shippedQty": 1,
                "receivedQty": 1

            }]

        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a problem with the payload.

You should use `requestSalesorderWrapper` instead of `RequestWrapper` in the wrapper Object

```
{
    "requestSalesorderWrapper": {
        "shipFromwarehouseSFDCId": "a4DS000000000zTMAQ",
        "shipFromwarehouseAccountId": "001S000000oBGkWIAW",
        "shipTowarehouseSFDCId": "a4DS000000000zTMAQ",
        "shipTowarehouseAccId": "001S000000oBGkWIAW",
        "vComments": "TEST COMMENTS",
        "orderType": "Purchase In",
        "govia_orderType": "Transfer",
        "sap_org_Id": "US29",
        "bolNumber": "888888",
        "productLines": [
            {
                "productId": "a2SS0000000HijIMAS",
                "uom": "BAG",
                "productDetailLines": [
                    {
                        "orderQty": 1,
                        "lotNumber": "345",
                        "shippedQty": 1,
                        "receivedQty": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Edit:

I saw that you are using the class names for ProductLine and details. Please use the variable names. See updated payload.

Comment: Thansk a lot for looking in this but i tried with your payload..still got the same error.

Comment: I have modified the answer. If you get an error again Please share the full error.

Comment: why do we need to use requestsalesforcewrapper insted of request wrapper?

Comment: Because that is the name you are giving to the instance of the class which will be formed at run-time, So you payload should match the instance variables else the  JSON parser will fail to map input JSON to class structure.

Comment: Sorry but i still didnt get the reaon..can you please share some links if available for this so that i can look into this

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
public List<ProductLine> productLines;
```

should be:

```
public List<ProductLine> ProductLine;
```

because the field name must match the name used in the JSON. The same sort of change is needed for the `recieveUnlistedConfirmOrder` parameter too.

(You might also have to change the `ProductLine` class name to a different name e.g. `MyProductLine`to avoid a name conflict.)

**PS**

This is the complementary change to manjit_singh's i.e. change the class to match the JSON instead of changing the JSON to match the class. You need to decide which way round you want to make the change. Assuming this doesn't work either, suggest you look in the debug logs for more detail.